# Integrate apache Cassandra with spree commerce framework

Tags: cassandra, spree

I'm planning to integrate apache cassandra with spree commerce framework for ruby. Is that possible?

Comment: Seems like we can not. any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you are a good enough programmer, yes you can use Cassandra to write software that need a database. Why do you ask?

Comment: Yes we can. But it would require lot of rewriting since spree commerce doesn't support other DBs than MySQL and PostgreSQL. I was wondering about some kind of adapter to workaround this.